# Regex how do you match a word without numbers and with a preset

Tags: regex

I am bashing my brain on how to do this, but can't seem to figure it out. I want to match the following:

- one_to_three -> MATCH
- three_to_four -> MATCH
- thr3_to_f5ve -> NOPE!

So basically I want to (match only words)(_to_)(match only words)

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `[a-z]+_to_[a-z]+` with `i` flag?

Comment: `[a-z]+_to_[a-z]+` That's all

Comment: Awww man... I was thinking too hard.. That actually helped! I just needed to change it a bit to `\b[a-z]+_to_[a-z]+\b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aight, thanks to the first two answers in the comments, it was fairly simple...

Using `\b[a-z]+_to_[a-z]+\b` to get what I need. Thanks!